# Showing $\int_1^{\infty } \frac{x^{-2}}{ s-x^{-2}} \, dx = \frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{s}}\right)}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{s}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

How do I derive the following?
$$\int_1^{\infty } \frac{x^{-2}}{ s-x^{-2}} \, dx = \frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{s}}\right)}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{s}}$$

Checking equality numerically, left-hand side (evaluated at discrete points using numerical integration) and the right hand-side (plotted continuously) for $s\in (100,1000)$
[image]

```
discretePlot = 
  DiscretePlot[
   NIntegrate[x^-2 1/(s - x^-2), {x, 1, \[Infinity]}], {s, 100, 1000, 
    10}];
continuousPlot = 
  Plot[ArcTan[Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[s]]/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[s]), {s, 100, 1000}];
Show[{discretePlot, continuousPlot}]
```

Comment: You can't derive something that isn't true. With the minus sign it is impossible for the derivative to be arctangent with positive $s$. The reason it looks true is because that fake answer has the same asymptotics as the real answer, $\sim \frac{1}{s}$ as $s\to\infty$.

Comment: Simplify and use partial fractions

Comment: @Gonçalo or more succintly as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}\right)$. Maybe now I can more see why OP thought the wrong answer was right.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the correct answer indeed matches better with the rest of the formulas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its easier to work with $s^2$

$\int_1^\infty \ \frac{dx} {s^2 \ x^2 -1} $

The indefinite integral decomposes into

$\frac{1}{2} \left(\int \frac{1}{s x-1} \, dx-\int \frac{1}{s x+1} \, dx\right) = \frac{1}{2s}( \log (s x-1)-\log (s x+1)) = ( \text{if s>1} ) \    \frac{1}{2s} \ \log(\frac{s x -1}{s x +1}) $

$\int_1^\infty \ \frac{dx} {s^2 \ x^2 -1} = \frac{1}{s} \tanh^{-1}(\frac{1}{s})  \  \ , \ s>1$

Somehow there is a confusion with $\tanh^{-1}(is) = i \arctan(s)$